# How to keep track of previous opened internal frames

Tags: java, user-interface

This is kind of an extension to my earlier question, but I am just wondering suppose at run time it makes multiple objects of a class (so it basically opens 4 internal frames) and display different images that are opened from different paths. So my questions if suppose the 4 frames are opened how would I get information of the path that opened the 2nd frame (so when the 2nd frame is opened I want to get it path (so when a certain frame is activated)), cause whenever I try calling getPath() - it gives me the most recent image path that has been opened but I don't know how to get information of previously opened frames.

(I used InternalFrameActivated() and that show which frame is activated and also gives the correct path but I don't know how to use it if suppose another class is calling that class). Does anybody have an idea of how to go about this?

Here is a link to my old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769006/how-to-get-information-from-previously-opened-internal-frame

Comment: A link to your previous question might help provide additional context

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry about that, this is a link to my previous question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769006/how-to-get-information-from-previously-opened-internal-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you opened the windows. You could create a factory/manager that would create a window for a specified path.

This would allow you to maintain a lookup mechanism so you could ask the manager for the windows for the specified path

**Updated with example**

There are a number of ways you might achieve this, personally I prefer a dynamically configurable approach, where by the manager you interface with acts as a proxy to some other, configurable, implementation of the manager.  This would allow you to plug in new/different managers that meet your needs over time, but that's quite a complex solution.

Instead, you could simply create a simple manager, using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)/enum approach, for example...

```
public enum PictureWindowManager {

    INSTANCE;

    private Map<Image, List<JInternalFrame>> mapWindows;

    private PictureWindowManager(){

        mapWindows = new HashMap<>(25);

    }

    public JInternalFrame createWindowFor(Image image) {

        List<JInternalFrame> frames = mapWindows.get(image);
        if (frames == null) {
            frames = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapWindows.put(image, frames);
        }
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Picture");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image))));
        frames.add(frame);

        return frame;

    }

    public List<JInternalFrame> getFromFor(Image image) {

        JInternalFrame frame = null;
        return mapWindows.get(image);

    }
}
```

Then you would create the window using something like...

```
JInternalFrame frame = PictureWindowManager.INSTANCE.createWindowFor(image);
```

Then when you wanted, you would retrieve the window(s) for an `Image` using something like...

```
List<JInternalFrame> frames = PictureWindowManager.INSTANCE.getFromFor(image);
```

Now, this example demonstrates an approach for allowing multiple windows for a single `Image`, you don't have to do this, you could simply maintain a one-to-one relationship between the `Image` and the `JInternalFrame` if that better meets your needs

Comment: So how would I create a factory manager for internal frames? I have no idea how I would go about writing this.

Comment: I open the windows by having a button under File -> open, then the user selects an image and then the internal frame opens within the desktop pane.

Comment: Sorry but I am really new to this, so the "private Map<Image, List<JInternalFrame>> mapWindows;" you are creating a map of type key of image and value of type List, where this contains a list of all internal frames opened correct? and where are you getting getInstance from? do you make a function where it returns the instance?

Comment: How would you make a 1-to-1 relationship?

Comment: Basically, instead of using Map<Image, List<JInternalFrame>> use Map<Image, JInternalFrame>. Obviously, we won't need the other references to List in the code ;)

Comment: Sorry, getInstance was a mistake, it should be INSTANCE