# Keeping track of windows and its information

Tags: java, user-interface

What my point of these two class below, are when a user suppose opens 5 windows (frames that contain images) and then a user clicks on the 2nd frame and wants the information about that image how do I get that frames information. In my previous question someone suggested to do the singleton enum and I kind of understood it and implemented but I just can't wrap my head around on how when a user clicks on a internal frame that the manager class will send the path to the Info class.

My earlier question: [How to keep track of previous opened internal frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770178/how-to-keep-track-of-previous-opened-internal-frames)

This is the Manager class:

```
public class Manager implements ActionListener{

private static int openFrameCount =0;
ImagePlus image;
private static String title;
final String SHOW ="show";
static ImageWindow m;
static JMenuItem showInfo;
static JMenuItem save;
static JDesktopPane desktop;
InfoGui in;
JMenuItem fft;

public Manager(ImagePlus img, String title, JDesktopPane desktop, JMenuItem save, JMenuItem fft, JMenuItem showInfo2){
    image = img;
    this.desktop = desktop;
    this.title = title;
    this.save = save;
    this.fft = fft;
    this.showInfo= showInfo;
}

public enum WindowManager implements InternalFrameListener, ComponentListener {

    INSTANCE;
    public MyInternalFrame frame;
    private Map<ImagePlus, List<MyInternalFrame>> mapWindows;

    private WindowManager(){

        mapWindows = new HashMap<>(25);

    }

    public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
        public MyInternalFrame(String title, ImagePlus img, JMenuItem save) {
            super(title, true,true, true, true);
            setSize(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());

            // Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
            save.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public JInternalFrame createWindowFor(ImagePlus image) {

        List<MyInternalFrame> frames = mapWindows.get(image);

        if (frames == null) {
            frames = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapWindows.put(image, frames);
        }

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ImageCanvas c = new ImageCanvas(image);
        c.getImage();

        //panel2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(c.getImage())));
         m = new ImageWindow(image);

        Image n = new Image();
        //frame = new MyInternalFrame(title, img, save,m);
        //ImageCanvas c = m.getCanvas();
        ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus();
        im.setImage(image);

        frame = new MyInternalFrame(image.getTitle(), image, save);
        m.centerNextImage();
        image.getCanvas().setScaleToFit(true);

        panel.add(m.getCanvas());
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(panel);
        frames.add(frame);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setOpaque(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

        }
        frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);  
        frame.addComponentListener(this);
        return frame;

    }

    public List<MyInternalFrame> getImage() {

        JInternalFrame frame = null;
        return mapWindows.get(title);

    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
        //showInfo.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
        //showInfo.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
        //showInfo.setEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();

        m.getCanvas().fitToWindow(r);
        System.out.println("resized- the real one");
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SADAPP.Manager.WindowManager.MyInternalFrame m = (SADAPP.Manager.WindowManager.MyInternalFrame) WindowManager.INSTANCE.createWindowFor(image);
}

 }
```

And this is my Info class:

```
public class Info implements ActionListener{

private static int openFrameCount =0;
ImagePlus image;
private static String title;
final String SHOW ="show";
static ImageWindow m;
JMenuItem showInfo;
static JMenuItem save;
static JDesktopPane desktop;
InfoGui in;
JMenuItem fft;

public Info(ImagePlus img, String title, JDesktopPane desktop, JMenuItem save, JMenu fft){
    image = img;
    this.desktop = desktop;
    this.title = title;
    this.save = save;
    this.fft = fft;
}

public enum WindowManager implements InternalFrameListener, ComponentListener {

    INSTANCE;
    public MyInternalFrame frame;
    private Map<ImagePlus, List<MyInternalFrame>> mapWindows;

    private WindowManager(){

        mapWindows = new HashMap<>(25);

    }

    public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
        public MyInternalFrame(String title, ImagePlus img, JMenuItem save) {
            super(title, true,true, true, true);
            setSize(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());

            // Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
            save.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public JInternalFrame createWindowFor(ImagePlus image) {

        List<MyInternalFrame> frames = mapWindows.get(image);

        if (frames == null) {
            frames = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapWindows.put(image, frames);
        }

        frame = new MyInternalFrame(image.getTitle(), image, save);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        String info = "Image Information: \n\n";
        info += "Image Name: "+image.getTitle()+ "\n";
        info += "Pixel Size: ";
        info += (image.getHeight() +" x "+image.getWidth() +"\n");
        info += ("Bit Depth: " + image.getBitDepth() + "-bit"+"\n");
        info+= "Bytes/Pixel: "+image.getBytesPerPixel() + "\n";
        info += "Type of: "+image.getType()+ "\n";
        info += "Diplay range: " + image.getDisplayRangeMax() +"\n";
        info += "Display range(min): " + image.getDefault16bitRange() + "\n";
        info += image.getFileInfo();
        info += image.getInfoProperty();
        //System.out.println(info);

        text.setText(info);
        System.out.println(image.getHeight());
        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setEditable(false);
        //text.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        panel.add(text);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

        ImageWindow m = new ImageWindow(image);
        panel2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image.getImage())));
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scroll, panel2);

        splitPane.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,100));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        panel2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(290);

        frame.add(splitPane);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

        }
       frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);  
        return frame;

    }

    public List<MyInternalFrame> getFromFor(ImagePlus image) {

        JInternalFrame frame = null;
        return mapWindows.get(title);

    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();

        m.getCanvas().fitToWindow(r);
        System.out.println("resized- the real one");
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JInternalFrame b = WindowManager.INSTANCE.createWindowFor(image);
}

 }
```

And in the main class, if the user clicks open and selects an image, I do:

```
 v= new Manager(img, s, desktop, save, fft,showInfo);
 ActionEvent e = null;
v.actionPerformed(e);
```

This opens the image window, and now suppose the user opens 4 more images, so this is called 4 more times. Now I want when a user click on a frame and then clicks showInfo, I want the info class to get the image title and display the info. So this is what I do:

```
List<MyInternalFrame> v =  WindowManager.INSTANCE.getImage();
ImagePlus i = new ImagePlus(v.get(0).getTitle());    //This is where the image is null
Info n = new Info(i,i.getTitle(), desktop, save, fft);
ActionEvent s = null;
n.actionPerformed(s);
```

This is where I am having troubles!!!!!! I hope anyone can spot the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one thing I see is that generally one would use `addActionListener()` to register a listener and not call `actionPerformed` directly normally in Java.  So like:

```
someComponent.addActionListener(new Manager());
```

So an action listener, your Manager, would have to be associated with an actual component